# Circuit Component for Amplifying Transmitted RF Signal?

Tags: amplifier, rf

I have an IC that transmits a weak RF signal and I'd like to extend the range.

What component should I add to amplify the signal: a power amplifier or a low noise amplifier?
 Why?

Comment: If your RF module transmits *and* receives, then adding *anything* between antenna and module is complicated: if you boost transmitted signal with a power amplifier, it will likely attenuate the receiving function. If you add a low-noise amplifier to boost received signal, transmitter will be attenuated (or your low-noise amp may die). A directional antenna may be easier. It boosts both transmit & receive signals.

Comment: Sounds like you need a power amp for a transmitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Power amplifiers are for transmitters, low noise amplifiers are for receivers.

Comment: I like your answer, but I think it would be even better with an explanation as to *why* a low-noise amplifier isn't needed in the transmitter, too.

Comment: I liked the answer to and I agree with Vladislav Martin

Comment: @roi_saumon I'll give my explanation: The differences between a power amplifier & low-noise amplifier are described in a concise manner [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237269/152002). Essentially, at the receiver you have a noisy signal (low SNR), so you use a LNA to amplify the signal without amplifying the noise & at the transmitter you have a low-noise signal (high SNR), so you use a PA to amplify the signal without worrying about unwanted random components.

Comment: @VladislavMartin - it's not possible to amplify a signal without amplifying the noise by the same ratio or more.  In fact any amplifier will add *even more* noise, worsening the signal to noise ratio by its own noise figure.  A low noise amplifier is one that tries to do this the least, ie, one with a low noise figure.

Comment: Right, that was an oversight. I was trying too hard to be concise. Comments are rarely well fleshed-out... could you incorporate the fully-correct explanation into your answer?

Comment: So I could in theory also use a LNA at the output stage and it would amplify my signal as well, no?

Comment: You could, but an LNA probably won't output much power, as it is designed to raise an extremely weak signal to a level where the rest of a receiver can handle it. Its maximum output level without distortion may well be below the level of signal your exciter is already producing. That said, there *are* receivers that reach higher internal power levels than some devices produce when transmitting (especially if it's an amplifier located at an antenna, which might then drive a substantial cable run).  But a receive amplifier isn't normally what one would choose for a transmitter final amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

If the radio link is one-way, then a power amplifier on the transmitter is generally better than a preamplifier on the receiver as a preamplifier will add noise to the received signal.

In general, an antenna with higher gain on both ends is a better solution as this increases the effective radiated power and improves the effective sensitivity of the receiving system.